# JQxScheduler How can I scroll vertically on the timeline view?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking for some basic schedulers where I can extend my own custom functionality. `JQxScheduler` looks pretty simple and light weight. I am trying to fiddle around with the timeline view's. The problem is I only see that they have horizontal scrolling. [Here is an example](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jseditor/?key=jqxscheduler-views). I have looked at the [API reference](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxscheduler/index.htm#demos/jqxscheduler/scheduler-configure-row-height.htm), but nothing stand's out to me.

The way it show's more appointments by clicking on a little arrow instead of scrolling isn't very user friendly. How can I customize this so I can scroll vertically?

I need this because I want to create a tree structure on the left hand side to sync vertical scrolling with the timeline view.

Incase the links don't work here is the code for the control.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var appointments = new Array();

    var appointment1 = {
        id: "id1",
        description: "George brings projector for presentations.",
        location: "",
        subject: "Quarterly Project Review Meeting",
        calendar: "Room 1",
        start: new Date(2015, 10, 23, 9, 0, 0),
        end: new Date(2015, 10, 23, 16, 0, 0)
    }

    var appointment2 = {
        id: "id2",
        description: "",
        location: "",
        subject: "IT Group Mtg.",
        calendar: "Room 2",
        start: new Date(2015, 10, 24, 10, 0, 0),
        end: new Date(2015, 10, 24, 15, 0, 0)
    }

    var appointment3 = {
        id: "id3",
        description: "",
        location: "",
        subject: "Course Social Media",
        calendar: "Room 3",
        start: new Date(2015, 10, 27, 11, 0, 0),
        end: new Date(2015, 10, 27, 13, 0, 0)
    }

    var appointment4 = {
        id: "id4",
        description: "",
        location: "",
        subject: "New Projects Planning",
        calendar: "Room 2",
        start: new Date(2015, 10, 23, 16, 0, 0),
        end: new Date(2015, 10, 23, 18, 0, 0)
    }

    var appointment5 = {
        id: "id5",
        description: "",
        location: "",
        subject: "Interview with James",
        calendar: "Room 1",
        start: new Date(2015, 10, 25, 15, 0, 0),
        end: new Date(2015, 10, 25, 17, 0, 0)
    }

    var appointment6 = {
        id: "id6",
        description: "",
        location: "",
        subject: "Interview with Nancy",
        calendar: "Room 4",
        start: new Date(2015, 10, 26, 14, 0, 0),
        end: new Date(2015, 10, 26, 16, 0, 0)
    }
    appointments.push(appointment1);
    appointments.push(appointment2);
    appointments.push(appointment3);
    appointments.push(appointment4);
    appointments.push(appointment5);
    appointments.push(appointment6);


    // prepare the data
    var source =
    {
        dataType: "array",
        dataFields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'description', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'location', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'subject', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'calendar', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'start', type: 'date' },
            { name: 'end', type: 'date' }
        ],
        id: 'id',
        localData: appointments
    };
    var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
    $("#scheduler").jqxScheduler({
        date: new $.jqx.date(2015, 11, 23),
        width: 850,
        height: 600,
        source: adapter,
        showLegend: false,
        ready: function () {
            $("#scheduler").jqxScheduler('ensureAppointmentVisible', 'id1');
        },
        resources:
        {
            colorScheme: "scheme05",
            dataField: "calendar",
            source:  new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source)
        },
        appointmentDataFields:
        {
            from: "start",
            to: "end",
            id: "id",
            description: "description",
            location: "place",
            subject: "subject",
            resourceId: "calendar"
        },
        view: 'timelineWeekView',
        views:
        [
            'timelineDayView',
            'timelineWeekView',
            'timelineMonthView'
        ]
    });
});`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the initial height based on number of appointments you want to show. That way timeline view will be able to accommodate all of them without down arrow.